Joomla Extension Update System Does Not Detect New Version XML Reading Problem?
I am developing joomla extensions. As you know There is an update system in Joomla and it works via xml. For example, there is a code in the extension xml file that reads this xml : https://www.joomlatema.net/update_server/joomla4/jt_testimonial.xml and detects the current version accordingly. Although the current version in this xml is 1.6, there is no update warning for the plugin version 1.0 or 1.2 on the sites. I have moved a new server for a while is that maybe due to new server xml reading issue. It seems like the sites do not see none of my extension updates. I have same issue for all of my extensions. I am sure that everything is well configured on extension xml and on server update xmls. Could this be a server-side xml reading problem? Howewer when i copy and paste xml url it displays correctly do that means server allows reaching xml.
here is my server info.php
https://www.joomlatema.net/info.php
Any idea? Thanks.

You mention plugin version 1.0 or 1.2 in your text but your update xml is for a module

Your target platform constraint is very strict. The update will appear only on sites running Joomla 4.4.8.

I think I solved the problem. I asked in the Joomla Facebook group Brian Teeman opened the window.
This line in the xml
<targetplatform name="joomla" version="4.4.8"/><client>site</client></update></updates>
means client site should definitely be the same version. I always perceived it as a minimum requirement
but I guess it's not. I think the version of the site that will be updated needs to be exactly the same
I did 4.4.8, it fixed that  thanks

It's a regular expression. This is documented in the new manual https://manual.joomla.org/docs/building-extensions/install-update/update-server/.
